# MySQL Query League script table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm currently working on a table for a League script.
These are my mysql tables: https://pastebin.com/raw/iuNbzGTS
This is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT
   name AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(L) AS L,SUM(Pts) AS Pts
FROM(
  SELECT
    teamid1 Team,
    1 P,
    IF(team1score > team2score,1,0) W,
    IF(team1score < team2score,1,0) L,
    CASE WHEN team1score > team2score THEN 1 WHEN team1score = team2score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
  FROM games
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    teamid2,
    1,
    IF(team1score < team2score,1,0),
    IF(team1score > team2score,1,0),
    CASE WHEN team1score < team2score THEN 1 WHEN team1score = team2score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM games
) as tot
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ;
```

The problem is that it just shows the teams which already played a match.  The other teams are not returned by the SQL query. I want to return the teams at the bottom of the table which haven't played a game yet. 
How can I do that?

Thank you 
With best regards

Comment: The magic words are `Left join`

Comment: Why are you using a link for ascii tables. You can as goog post them in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
FROM    teams t 
LEFT JOIN
        (
        ... your subquery here ...
        ) as tot
ON      tot.Team = t.id
```

Comment: Thank you, Thats the new query: https://pastebin.com/XJj0aC0G But it just Shows only one Team which has played now match so far but there are multiple Teams in the Teams table which has played no Matches. Regards

Comment: The query you link should return all teams. Perhaps you can set up a sqlfiddle.com query to reproduce the problem?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9jN5nmQeX4KEnBn7vYKcPH/0 If i try to run the query it always Shows the error message:  Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.t.tname' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @Maro: You can't refer to aliases in `group by`. Change `group by team` to `group by tname`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. How can I replace the NULL with a "0". It only should show the Teams where the coolum 'activted' is 1 in the "teams" table?

Comment: The `coalesce` function returns the first argument that is not `null`. So you can replace `null` like `coalesce(col1, '0')`. You can filter for active teams by adding `where activated = 1` before the `group by`